# How to set the 'show' parameter in tkinter Entry to default value after it has been set to show="*"?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am making a GUI with Tkinter in which the start menu gives the user an option to switch between a student account and admin account. For a student, a name is needed while for an admin a password is required  which can be input into the **same entry box**. The password needs to be hidden by asterisks (*) where as this is not necessary for name inputs.

after switching once from student to admin account, the next time I want to change the entry box back to normal text view for a student account.
here is a stripped down version of my code.

```
admin = False
def switchUser():
    global admin
    if admin:
        admin = False
        userEntry.config(show='*')
        titleLabel.config(text='Enter the password')
    else:
        admin = True
        #code to switch back to default text view in entry box
        titleLabel.config(text='Enter your name')

titleLabel = Label(startMenu, text='Enter your name')
userEntry = Entry(startMenu)
adminButton = (startMenu, text='Admin', command=switchUser)
```

Comment: `<tkinter.Entry>.config(show="")`

Comment: Also I think you are missing `Button` on the last line before the `(startMenu, text='Admin', command=switchUser)`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `show` option to the empty string.

```
userEntry.configure(show="")
```